# What is the best way to reuse a scope in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, rubygems

I'm confused to reuse or writing a new scope.
for example,

one of my methods will return future subscription or current subscription or sidekiq created subscriptions.

as scopes will look like:

```
scope :current_subscription, lambda {
    where('(? between from_date and to_date) and (? between from_time and to_time)', Time.now, Time.now)
  }

  scope :sidekiq_created_subscription, lambda {
    where.not(id: current_subscription).where("(meta->'special_sub_enqueued_at') is not null")
  }

  scope :future_subscription, lambda {
    where.not(id: current_subscription).where("(meta->'special_sub_enqueued_at') is null")
  }
```

so these were used for separate purposes in different methods, so for me what I tried is to check whether a particular account record will come under which of three subscriptions.

so I tried like:

```
def find_account_status
    accounts = User.accounts
    name = 'future' if accounts.future_subscription.where(id: @account.id).any? 
    name = 'ongoing' if accounts.current_subscription.where(id: @account.id).any? 
    name = 'sidekiq' if accounts.sidekiq_enqued_subscription.where(id: @account.id).any? 
return name
    end
```

so here what my doubt is, whether using like this is a good way, as here we will be fetching the records based on the particular subscriptions and then we are checking whether ours is there or not.

can anyone suggest any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Your approach does work but you need up to 3 additional database queries to determine the account's status. I usually write corresponding predicate methods for such scopes, e.g. `def current_subscription?` which checks the in-memory model attributes via `Time.current.between?(from_date, to_date)`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are over using the scopes here.

The method `#find_account_status` will execute around 4 Queries as below:

Q1 => `accounts = User.accounts`
Q2 => `accounts.future_subscription`
Q3 => `accounts.current_subscription`
Q4 => `accounts.sidekiq_enqued_subscription`

Your functionality can be achived by simply using the `@account` object which is already present in memory as below:

1. Add below instance methods in the model:

```
    def current_subscription?
      # Here I think just from_time and to_time will do the work
      # but I've added from_date and to_date as well based on the logic in the question
      Time.now.between?(from_date, to_date) && Time.now.between?(from_time, to_time)
    end


    def future_subscription?
      !current_subscription? && meta["special_sub_enqueued_at"].blank?
    end


    def sidekiq_future_subscription?
      !current_subscription? && meta["special_sub_enqueued_at"].present?
    end
```

2. `#find_account_status` can be refactored as below:

```
  def find_account_status
    if @account.current_subscription?
      'ongoing'
    elsif @account.future_subscription?
      'future'
    elsif @account.sidekiq_future_subscription?
      'sidekiq'
    end
  end
```

Additionally, as far as I've understood the code, I think you should also handle a case wherein the from_date and to_date are past dates because if that is not handled, the status can be set based on the field meta["special_sub_enqueued_at"] which can provide incorrect status.

e.g. Let's say that the `from_date` in the account is set as 31st Dec 2021 and `meta["special_sub_enqueued_at"]` is false or nil.
In this case, `#current_subscription?` will return false but `#future_subscription?` will return true which is incorrect, and hence the case for past dates should be handled.